# SCSS mixin with argument interpolation is not working

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm creating a mixin to generate a CSS background gradient, per [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

The mixin looks like this:

```
@mixin gradient-2-colors($color-1, $color-1-pos, $color-2, $color-2-pos) {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, $color-1 $color-1-pos, $color-2 $color-2-pos);
  ... [OTHER BROWSER-SPECIFIC ENTRIES]...
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='$color-1', endColorstr=\'$color-2\',GradientType=0 );
}
```

and the last entry is giving me trouble, since `$color-1` in `startColorstr='$color-1'` is not being parsed as a variable! How can I escape this component of the mixin to make the variable work inside of quotes?

Comment: `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=$color1, endColorstr=$color2, GradientType=0);` isn't working either... :<

Comment: You will save yourself a lot of headaches if you use Compass. It comes with lots of mixins for things like [gradients](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/).

Comment: @bookcasey: I am using Compass... will take a look. Thank you.

Comment: Specifically this mixin: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/#mixin-filter-gradient for the old IE stuff.

Comment: @bookcasey: Really appreciate you pointing out that Compass is a CSS Frameowkr and not just a CLI tool (had never even gone to it's homepage until now! This is quite Bootstrap-like in many ways. Really, many thanks. Unfortunately, I've also got some linear gradients with 3 stops. It appears compass only does 2 stops.

Comment: No, wait, totally wrong: from: http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/gradient/ `#v-gradient-3 {
  @include background-image(linear-gradient(white, #cccccc 30%, #bbbbbb 70%, #aaaaaa)); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#{$color-1}', endColorstr=\'#{$color-2}\',GradientType=0 );
```

Comment: Truth, that works. Gracias. Don't know how I missed that in the docs.